# Display Date if valid Date using angular.isDate(value)

Tags: angularjs

Why can't I directly use angular.isDate in the Binding. Something like:

```
{{(angular.isDate(cdate.customStartDate)? cdate.customStartDate | date : format : timezone : 'Please select'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose isDate from the controller.

Like `$scope.isDate = angular.isDate`

If it isnt on the scope, it cannot be seen by your view.

But like what jsmtslch said, this logic would be better served in the controller. Something along the line of

```
$scope.isCorrectDate = function (targetDate){return angular.isDate(cdate.CustomStartDate))}
```

then you can use in your view

```
{{isCorrectDate(cdate.CustomStartDate) ? cdate.customStarteDate | date: format:timezone :'Please Select'
```

Comment: I tried that but I get the error: angular.min.js:84 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/ng/areq?p0=FullcalendarCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)     I think it happes when cdate.CustomStartDate is NaN or undefined because NaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined also appears in the error trace

Comment: @dave The error you pasted looks like you aren't declaring you control properly. Will you paste your full javascript in a plunkr/jsfiddle so we can tweek it